# HTMX and chart JS

Tags: charts, htmx

I was wondering if it was possible to issue an htmx get request to an html block containing a chartJS canvas.
I have a piece of html containing a canvas generated with Chart JS that get called with an HTMX get request but I am unable to generate the chart once the get request is complete.

I have put all the dependencies of chart js in the main html but It is not working.
I also tried to put all the dependencies in the html fragment that gets called by the HTMX GET request but it is not working either.

Is it possible?

Here is what I have so far:

Original

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.6.1" integrity="sha384-tvG/2mnCFmGQzYC1Oh3qxQ7CkQ9kMzYjWZSNtrRZygHPDDqottzEJsqS4oUVodhW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <div id="mainAjax" class="slide-in-left-fade-in fade-me-out fade-in">
            <button 
            class=""
            hx-get="/data-viz/simple-chart"
            hx-target="#mainAjax" 
            hx-swap="outerHTML swap:0.2s" 
            hx-select="#mainAjax"
            hx-trigger="myEvent from:body">
                Get canvas
            </button>
        </div>

        <script>
            document.body.addEventListener("myEvent", function(evt) {
                alert("trigger is working")
            })


        </script>

        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hammerjs@2.0.8"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/chartjs-plugin-zoom/1.2.0/chartjs-plugin-zoom.min.js" integrity="sha512-TT0wAMqqtjXVzpc48sI0G84rBP+oTkBZPgeRYIOVRGUdwJsyS3WPipsNh///ay2LJ+onCM23tipnz6EvEy2/UA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

        
    </body>
</html>
```

and the Canvas Im trying to fetch:

```
<div id="mainAjax"class="">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.7.0/chart.min.js" integrity="sha512-TW5s0IT/IppJtu76UbysrBH9Hy/5X41OTAbQuffZFU6lQ1rdcLHzpU5BzVvr/YFykoiMYZVWlr/PX1mDcfM9Qg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

    <canvas class="my-4 w-100 chartjs-render-monitor" id="myChart" width="1110" height="468" style="display: block; height: 521px; width: 1234px;"></canvas>


    <script>
    const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

    var config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        labels : ['2005-03-31', '2005-06-30', '2005-09-30', '2005-12-31', '2006-03-31', '2006-06-30', '2006-09-30', '2006-12-31', '2007-03-31', '2007-06-30', '2007-09-30', '2007-12-31', '2008-03-31', '2008-06-30', '2008-09-30', '2008-12-31', '2009-03-31', '2009-06-30', '2009-09-30', '2009-12-31', '2010-03-31', '2010-06-30', '2010-09-30', '2010-12-31', '2011-03-31', '2011-06-30', '2011-09-30', '2011-12-31', '2012-03-31', '2012-06-30', '2012-09-30', '2012-12-31', '2013-03-31', '2013-06-30', '2013-09-30', '2013-12-31', '2014-03-31', '2014-06-30', '2014-09-30', '2014-12-31', '2015-03-31', '2015-06-30', '2015-09-30', '2015-12-31', '2016-03-31', '2016-06-30', '2016-09-30', '2016-12-31', '2017-03-31', '2017-06-30', '2017-09-30', '2017-12-31', '2018-03-31', '2018-06-30', '2018-09-30', '2018-12-31', '2019-03-31', '2019-06-30', '2019-09-30', '2019-12-31', '2020-03-31', '2020-06-30', '2020-09-30', '2020-12-31', '2021-03-31', '2021-06-30', '2021-09-30'],
        datasets: [{
            label: 'AAPL Revenue',
            lineTension: 0,
            data: [3243.0, 3520.0, 3678.0, 5749.0, 4359.0, 4370.0, 4837.0, 7115.0, 5264.0, 5410.0, 6789.0, 9608.0, 7512.0, 7464.0, 12907.0, 11880.0, 9084.0, 9734.0, 12207.0, 15683.0, 13499.0, 15700.0, 20343.0, 26741.0, 24667.0, 28571.0, 28270.0, 46333.0, 39186.0, 35023.0, 35966.0, 54512.0, 43603.0, 35323.0, 37472.0, 57594.0, 45646.0, 37432.0, 42123.0, 74599.0, 58010.0, 49605.0, 51501.0, 75872.0, 50557.0, 42358.0, 46852.0, 78351.0, 52896.0, 45408.0, 52579.0, 88293.0, 61137.0, 53265.0, 62900.0, 84310.0, 58015.0, 53809.0, 64040.0, 91819.0, 58313.0, 59685.0, 64698.0, 111439.0, 89584.0, 81434.0, 83360.0],
            backgroundColor: '#A3BE8C4D',
            fill: false,
            showLine : true,
            borderColor: 

            '#A3BE8C'
            ,
            borderWidth: 1
        }],

    },
    }

    var myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);
    console.log(myChart.data.datasets)

    document.body.addEventListener("cart-updated",
        function (evt) {
            alert("cart updated")
        })

    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible, you have to trigger a redraw after HTMX request using e.g. [HX-Tigger](https://htmx.org/headers/hx-trigger/) response header.

Comment: You mean like destroy the chart and create a new one?

Comment: That can work as well, depending on your code. If you look at [Chart.js's API](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html) there's also an `.update()` method that can be used if you load new data points via HTMX and you only need to trigger an update on the chart. But destroying the old chart and creating a new one after HTMX request is also a solution. Share a minimal (semi-)working example then we can help you with the details.

Comment: @Dauros I added an example of what I have but I'm really not sure how to put that into a codepen since htmx depends on other urls

Comment: @Dauros I also noticed that when I specify a target on the htmx get, the canvas doesnt load at all

Comment: Alrigth, so I got it to work on this little example by adding the ChartJS dependency on the original html. I'm pretty sure that I have tried that on my actual project but for some reason, it is not working (I guess I'll have to look deeper into that). I didn't need to trigger any update() or to reconstruct the chart  in order to generate the canvas. Thank you for inciting me to address this problem into a smaller example.

Comment: No problem! In the main template you load 2 Chart.js-related plugins, for that you have to load the base Chart.js library first. I recommend to include all these external scripts in the base HTML template, so the user's browser has to execute them only once.

Comment: I just figured out what the problem was in my actual project and just saw your comment now: That was exactly my problem! Thank you so much!